# Automate group generation according to intervals in string

Tags: r

I have data on covariates for several units. Additionally, I have access to a *scoring rule* that ranks my observations according to a score.

I decided to divide my training sample `X` according to the quantiles of `score`, which I achieved by using the `quantile_group` function from the `GenericMl` package.

```
## Generate data.
set.seed(1986)

n <- 1000
n_val <- 10000
k <- 3

X <- matrix(rnorm(n * k), ncol = k)
X_val <- matrix(rnorm(n_val * k), ncol = k)

score <- rexp(n) 
score_val <- rexp(n_val)   

## Quantiles of score.
library(GenericML)
groups <- quantile_group(score)
head(groups)
#>      [-Inf, 0.277) [0.277, 0.678) [0.678, 1.34) [1.34, Inf]
#> [1,]          TRUE          FALSE         FALSE       FALSE
#> [2,]         FALSE          FALSE         FALSE        TRUE
#> [3,]         FALSE          FALSE          TRUE       FALSE
#> [4,]         FALSE           TRUE         FALSE       FALSE
#> [5,]         FALSE           TRUE         FALSE       FALSE
#> [6,]         FALSE          FALSE          TRUE       FALSE
```

The *g*-th column of `groups` consists of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s denoting membership to the *g*-th quantile of `score`. My next step is to divide units in the validation sample `X_val` using the same partition of `groups`. To clarify, I want to divide `score_val` in four groups defined by the intervals given by `colnames(groups)`:

```
colnames(groups)
#> [1] "[-Inf, 0.277)"  "[0.277, 0.678)" "[0.678, 1.34)"  "[1.34, Inf]"
```

I need to automate this.

Comment: `X[which(groups[,1]==TRUE),]` will give you the rows of your datat to consider in the first training data set, and so on `X[which(groups[,i]==TRUE),]` Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how can this help me in dividing units in the validation sample `X_val`? I need to group all units in this data set that have `score_val` between `"[-Inf, 0.277)"` and similarly for the other intervals.

Comment: Well, those units whose `score_val` is in `"[-Inf, 0.277)"` are the rows with a `TRUE` in the first column of your `groups` object. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, those rows correspond to units whose `score` is in `"[-Inf, 0.277)"`. I need to take this interval (and the others) to partition `score_val` in the same way. I need four vectors: The first one would be `score_val < 0.277`, the second one would be `0.277 <= score_val & score_val < 0.678`, and so on. I am having a hard time automating this.

Comment: Using the `cut` function `cut(score_val,breaks = c(-Inf, 0.277,0.678,1.34,Inf))`

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice starting point. However, I need to automate this in a loop, where `score` (and thus the intervals) change at each iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249419/discussion-between-r18-and-plastic-man).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be an approach to get what you are looking for. I don't use the `GenericML` package because If I understood well, you only want to divide `X_val` into sub-sets.

```
# Load library
  library(dplyr)

# Generate data
  set.seed(1986)
  n <- 1000
  n_val <- 10000
  k <- 3

  X <- matrix(rnorm(n * k), ncol = k)
# Here I use "as.data.frame.matrx" in order to add the group (according to the interval)
  X_val <- as.data.frame.matrix(matrix(rnorm(n_val * k), ncol = k))

  score <- rexp(n) 
  score_val <- rexp(n_val)   

# Get the quantiles of score  
  q.score <- quantile(score)
# Divide score_val acording to the quantiles of q.score
  group.var <- cut(score_val, breaks = c(-Inf, q.score[2:4], Inf))
  
# Add "group.var" to X_val matrix
  X_val$group.var <- group.var

# Divide the information according to "group.var" 
  new_X_val <- X_val %>%
               group_split(group.var)
```

At the end, what you get is `new_X_val`, a list with 4 elements, one for each quantile.